# Pyinstaller not writing to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm, pyinstaller

I have a program that decrypts chrome saved info and puts it into a file. I am trying to turn it into an .exe from .py but when run, does not work.

My code is

```py
import base64
import json
import os
import shutil
import sqlite3
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from win32crypt import CryptUnprotectData


def get_chrome_datetime(chromedate):
    """Return a `datetime.datetime` object from a chrome format datetime
    Since `chromedate` is formatted as the number of microseconds since January, 1601"""
    return datetime(1601, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=chromedate)

def get_encryption_key():
    local_state_path = os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"],
                                    "AppData", "Local", "Google", "Chrome",
                                    "User Data", "Local State")
    with open(local_state_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        local_state = f.read()
        local_state = json.loads(local_state)

    # decode the encryption key from Base64
    key = base64.b64decode(local_state["os_crypt"]["encrypted_key"])
    # remove DPAPI str
    key = key[5:]
    # return decrypted key that was originally encrypted
    # using a session key derived from current user's logon credentials
    # doc: http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32crypt.html
    return CryptUnprotectData(key, None, None, None, 0)[1]

def decrypt_password(password, key):
    try:
        # get the initialization vector
        iv = password[3:15]
        password = password[15:]
        # generate cipher
        cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
        # decrypt password
        return cipher.decrypt(password)[:-16].decode()
    except:
        try:
            return str(CryptUnprotectData(password, None, None, None, 0)[1])
        except:
            # not supported
            return ""

def main():
    global origin_url, action_url, username, password
    key = get_encryption_key()
    db_path = os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"], "AppData", "Local",
                            "Google", "Chrome", "User Data", "default", "Login Data")
    # copy the file to another location
    # as the database will be locked if chrome is currently running
    filename = "ChromeData.db"
    shutil.copyfile(db_path, filename)
    # connect to the database
    db = sqlite3.connect(filename)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    # `logins` table has the data we need
    cursor.execute("select origin_url, action_url, username_value, password_value, date_created, date_last_used from logins order by date_created")
    # iterate over all rows
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        origin_url = row[0]
        action_url = row[1]
        username = row[2]
        password = decrypt_password(row[3], key)
        date_created = row[4]
        date_last_used = row[5]
        with open('out.txt', 'a') as f:
            with redirect_stdout(f):
                print(f'\nOrigin URL: {origin_url}'
                        f'\nAction URL: {action_url}'
                        f'\nUsername: {username}'
                        f'\nPassword: {password}',
                        f'\n', '=' * 50)
        if username or password:
            print(f"Origin URL: {origin_url}")
            print(f"Action URL: {action_url}")
            print(f"Username: {username}")
            print(f"Password: {password}")
        else:
            continue

        if date_created != 86400000000 and date_created:
            print(f"Creation date: {str(get_chrome_datetime(date_created))}")
        if date_last_used != 86400000000 and date_last_used:
            print(f"Last Used: {str(get_chrome_datetime(date_last_used))}")
        print("="*50)

    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
    except:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When turned from .py to .exe with pyinstaller, the program turns successfully but the exe will not run. I ran it through cmd and got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
[13152] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I have crypto installed on pycharm as well with pip to my machine.